# MySQL - How to list all volunteers who worked no more than once per calendar year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of volunteer worker sessions going back several years. Each entry contains, among other things, the name of a volunteer, the date of a session, and the number of hours worked that day. (Yes, volunteers are identified by name only, with no protection against matching names. I didn't set this up, unfortunately.) I want to get a list of all volunteers who appear, at most, once in each calendar year. (AKA "episodic" volunteers.)  How would I write this query?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: How is your table(s) defined, which columns it contains?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from USERS where id in (
select u.id from 
(
  select
    u.id, count(*)
  from 
    USERS u
  where
    YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
  group by 
    name
  Having 
    Count(name) <= 1
))
```

I couldn't test this out, but i guess this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
SELECT   `name`,
         COUNT(`name`) AS `value_occurrence` 
FROM     `my_table`
WHERE YEAR(START_DATE) = YEAR(CURDATE()
GROUP BY `name`
ORDER BY `value_occurrence` DESC
LIMIT    1;
```

The top record will be most appeared volunteer.